# Imagemagick ampersand in directory

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am converting images using imagemagick from php. I have a directory name that contains ampersand. When I issue a command from php using exec it does not work for the directory that contains ampersand (&) sign. Can anyone help me how to solve this problem? I can't rename the directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the directory name in single-quotes. This should disable the special meaning of the ampersand.

Comment: Yes I did that. Here is my command
/usr/bin/convert '/tmp/phpJ1IK8y' -coalesce -scale 120x90 '/root/a&b/shots.gif'